# Cannot seem to get a line drawn between the pixels that are my Bezier Curve. Python / Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I can not seem draw lines between the old pixel and the new pixel making a smooth Bezier curve.  I have the Bezier curve, but it is only made up of pixels alone.  Also, when I click on the canvas to update the Bezier curve I can't get the old one to delete.  I have tried canvas.delete(line) and also canvas.delete(tk.ALL), but this gets rid of everything and i need to be able to keep my click_points or the where the ovals where drawn.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import tkinter as tk


#Screen creation.
        SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
        SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800
        SIZE = 4


**# Creates the canvas.**
        root_window = tk.Tk()
        canvas = tk.Canvas(root_window, width = SCREEN_WIDTH, height = SCREEN_HEIGHT)

        canvas.pack()

**#Plots each pixel**
        def plot_pixel(x0, y0):
                line = canvas.create_line(x0, y0, x0 + 1, y0)

**#Pre: Takes a list of points.
#Post: Recursively iterates through the list to find the 
#      linear interpolation (x, y)**           
        def draw_curve(points, t):
            if len(points) == 1:
                plot_pixel(points[0][0], points[0][1])
            else:
                newpoints = []
                for i in range(0, len(points) - 1):
                    # old_point_x = (1 - t) * points[i - 1][0] + t * points[i][0]
                    # old_point_y = (1 - t) * points[i - 1][1] + t * points[i][1]
                    x = (1 - t) * points[i][0] + t * points[i + 1][0]
                    y = (1 - t) * points[i][1] + t * points[i + 1][1]
                    newpoints.append((x, y))
                draw_curve(newpoints, t)
```

Recursion call to draw_curve while t <= 1.
            def draw(points):
                t = 0
                while t <= 1:
                    draw_curve(points, t)
                    t += 0.01

```
    #Mouse B-1 bound, for every click draw an oval and append to
        #list -- click_points.
        click_points = []
        def click(event):
            click_points.append((event.x, event.y))
            oval = canvas.create_oval(event.x - SIZE,
                                      event.y - SIZE,
                                      event.x + SIZE,
                                      event.y + SIZE,
                                      fill = "red")
            draw(click_points)


        canvas.bind("<Button-1>", click)   

        root_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: are you aware that Tkinter can draw bezier curves natively? Or is this an exercise in learning how to manually draw curves?

Comment: When you say "I have tried canvas.delete(line) ", what is the result of that trying? Assuming that `line` indeed holds the id of an item, this _will_ delete that line.

Comment: Yes I am aware that Tkinter can draw them.  This is an assignment that I am learning how to manually do it.  Right now the (x, y) of the linear interpolation is just pixels.(like a dotted line instead of a continuous whole line)  When i run the program and after clicking on the canvas twice the algorithm will draw a dotted line b/w the two points. If i click a third time I get a Bezier curve, but the original line b/w point1 and point2 needs to be deleted, leaving only the Bezier curve on the screen.

Comment: My results from canvas.delete(line) were nothing.  I was unsuccessful in getting the previous line to delete after a new one was drawn.